# Question about Matter power spectrum

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics

I'm a bit confused about the statements in the following text:

> If the autocorrelation function [$\xi$] describes the probability of a galaxy at a distance $r$ from another galaxy, the matter power spectrum [$P(\mathbf{k},t)$] decomposes this probability into characteristic lengths, $k\approx 2\pi/L$, and its amplitude describes the degree to which each characteristic length contributes to the total over-probability.
>
> The overall shape of the matter power spectrum is best understood in terms of the linear perturbation theory analysis of the growth of structure, which predicts to first order that the power spectrum grows according to:
> $${\displaystyle P(\mathbf {k} ,t)=D_{+}^{2}(t)\cdot P(\mathbf {k} ,t_{0})=D_{+}^{2}(t)\cdot P_{0}(\mathbf {k} )}$$
> where $\displaystyle D_{+}(t)$ is the *linear growth factor* in the density, that is to first order $\displaystyle \delta (r,t)=D_{+}(t)\delta _{0}(r)$, and $\displaystyle P_{0}(\mathbf {k} )$ is commonly referred to as the *primordial matter power spectrum*.

(taken from [Wikipedia, Matter power spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_power_spectrum))

If I'm not mistaken the autocorrelation function $\xi$ tells me how probable it is to find a galaxy at distance $r$, given one at another position. The second part of this sentence seems weird to me. What does it mean to "decompose a probability into characteristic lengths" and what exactly is a "over-probability"?

I'm also a bit confused about the second part of the quote (From "The overall shape..." on). Reading this I would think one can connect the primordial power spectrum $P_0(\mathbf{k})$ with the current one $P(\mathbf{k}, t)$ by the linear growth factor $D_+(t)$, but doesn't one need the transfer function $T(\mathbf{k})$ for this? I don't really see where this comes into play here...